# How can I edit my Menu Border Animation? [WordPress]

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I created an Elementor Menu with a menu item border animation using code as shown below. However, on hover state it begins with black line:

Here is the Site link:

[link](https://t.ly/GFAIR)

Here is my CSS:

```
#stickyheaders .e-n-menu-items-heading .e-n-menu-item-title::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-style: none; 
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#stickyheaders .e-n-menu-items-heading .e-n-menu-item-title:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
     border-bottom-style: none; 
}
```

Why does the animated border start with a black dotted line and how can I adjust my code to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS and try.

```
#stickyheaders .e-n-menu-items-heading .e-n-menu-item-title:hover::after {
       border-left: #E2E2E2 !important;
}
```